# Where to see PHP build-in web server log or something?

Tags: php, http-status-code-500, php-builtin-server

I took someone's PHP project with a bunch of PHP files and ran it with the following command

```
C:\tools\php71\php.exe -S localhost:8080 -t PATHTOSOMELOCATION
```

Now, when I am opening http://localhost:8080 I am getting error 500.

Where to see what is going on? Some logs?

Answer (score -1):

**if xampp is your web server it will be in**

```
\xampp\apache\logs\error.log
```